# Android проблемы с автозагрузкой сервиса

Tags: android, service

Доброго времени суток! После дня прочесывания интернета таки решил обратиться к вам. Вся проблема: при включении android'а не запускается receiver, соответственно не запускается служба.  Видимо сам я уже не в состоянии заметить ошибку. Рассчитываю на вашу помощь.

Код receiver'а:

```
public class MyBroadReceiv extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public MyBroadReceiv() {
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, com.example.hp3520.gsp.MyNewService.class));
    }
}
```

И манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.hp3520.gsp"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_percent_18e_svg"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme = "@style/MyTheme"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyBroadReceiv"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyNewService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Для того, что бы ресивер сработал, приложение должно хотя бы один раз быть запущено юзером и не остановлено принудительно (через меню в настройках приложений, таск-киллером каким-нибудь, или ошибкой), а так же в устройстве может быть приложение для управления автозапуском, которое будет блокировать Ваш ресивер. И пермишен в теге ресивера лишний, по-моему.

Comment: Все правильно сделано, код корректный. Ищи ошибку внутри сервиса. И на будущее не забывай читать логи, там как правило все подробно описано почему что-то не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выставить ресиверу атрибут `android:exported="true"` - должно помочь

Comment: Пока ничего не помогает. При этом смог выяснить, что если сразу после включения телефона открыть программу, receiver сработает.